# What programming languages can one use to create shared/dynamic libraries?

Tags: dll, shared-libraries, dylib, dynamic-library

I know that C and C++ can easily create shared libraries, but I want something that also helps me. D looked promising, but I find it hard and clunky to write in, especially without good IDE support (the VS plugin is the best by far but it's still limited). Kotlin also could have been a choice, but it lacks any standard library to do stuff like file management (for example renaming a file).

I am looking for a language (preferably object oriented) with a good standard library that can create shared libraries (.dll, .dylib, .so) in Windows, macOS and Linux that can then be used by any langauge that supports C foreign functions (for example, from Python with ctypes).

Is there such thing?

Comment: You can't create a library that you can call from Python or Ruby or even C using Java. Java doesn't compile to machine code, it is run using the JVM.

Answer (score 2):

> What programming languages can one use to create shared/dynamic libraries?

You can make a shared/dynamic library using any [compiled language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language)
or combination of compiled
languages that compile to [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file), provided that all the
contributing compilers are [ABI compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).

That is because creating a shared library is a matter of [linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing))
a number of object files that have been produced beforehand by some compiler or compilers,
possibly together with other shared/dynamic libraries, in a manner that directs the linker to output a shared/dynamic library, (e.g with the `-shared`
linkage option of the GNU linker, or the `/DLL` option of Microsoft linker). The linker is not cognisant of the source language or languages from which its inputs were compiled.

As to which compiled language you would find most satisfactory, my opinion or recommendation
would be off-topic.

Comment: Why would it be off-topic?

Comment: @DanCojocaru Because questions inviting opinion-based answers and/or software recommendation anwsers are [off-topic on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
Your question has escaped closure because the headline question is on-topic
although the "I am looking for a language...Is there such thing?" question is off-topic.